# Enforcing composition in Python with mypy

Tags: python, composition, mypy, python-3.9, enforcement

Say I have some code where I expect a class possessing some characteristics like attributes or methods, but I don't want to use inheritance to enforce this, preferring composition instead.

How would I go about enforcing that the class/object received as argument actually presents these characteristics?

Example with inheritance:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class FooBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass

class Foo(FooBase):
    def do_stuff(self):
        return 'hello'

def some_function(obj: FooBase):
    print(obj.do_stuff())
```

In this above example, `some_function` is enforcing (statically through MyPy) that the `obj` parameter is a subclass of `FooBase`.

Instead, I'd like that `some_function` enforces (statically, via MyPy) that `obj` has a `do_stuff` method, without it necessarily being a subclass of `FooBase`.

Comment: Even without the type annotations your function is already enforcing that the parameter has a `do_stuff()` method.

Comment: BTW, I don't think type annotation actually *enforce* anything.

Comment: @topsail "enforce" as in "mypy-enforce"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typing.Protocol`:

```
from typing import Protocol

class Foo(Protocol):
    def do_stuff(self) -> str: ...

class Bar:
    def do_stuff(self) -> str:
        return "hello"

def some_function(obj: Foo):
    print(obj.do_stuff())


some_function(Bar())  # ok
```

The difference between a `Protocol` and an `ABC` is that you can implement a protocol without explicitly inheriting from it, so `Bar` is considered a `Foo` by mypy even though it's not a subclass of `Foo`.

If you pass a type that doesn't implement the protocol, you get an error, e.g.:

```
class Baz:
    def do_stuff(self) -> int:
        return 42

some_function(Baz())  
# error: Argument 1 to "some_function" has incompatible type "Baz"; expected "Foo"
# note: Following member(s) of "Baz" have conflicts:
# note:     Expected:
# note:         def do_stuff(self) -> str
# note:     Got:
# note:         def do_stuff(self) -> int
```

Comment: oh I see. That's very interesting. Would there be a way to enforce that `obj` has an `__init__` method that expects e.g. **at least** one parameter `myarg: str` but can also expect other parameters, that the implementing class (Bar/Baz) would need but not required by the protocol (Foo)?

Comment: like `def __init__(self, myarg: str, *args: Any)`?  I don't see why not.

Comment: basically I want to enforce that `obj` has an `__init__` method that expects `myarg: str`) but also leave the liberty to this `__init__` to expect additional parameters

Comment: exactly this, but the problem with `*args` or `**kwargs` is that in this case, Bar has no way of enforcing statically that **its** expected parameters are satisfied

Comment: This sounds like a separate question -- or you could just try it out.  :)

Comment: there is actually a separate question here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668164/abstract-method-allowing-for-additional-arguments

Comment: I tried every approach I could think of, and I didn't know about this protocol approach so thanks already for mentioning it

Comment: I'm accepting this answer anyway b/c it does answer the question as formulated

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why on earth you'd want this for `__init__` specifically.  Why would you care about an ABC's (or a Protocol's) constructor as long as after it's been constructed it implements the right behavior?  I don't think I've *ever* seen an abstract class with any kind of constructor, since by definition you can't construct them.  If the idea is that you have a function that takes a type/constructor with a particular signature as a function, you can do that with a Protocol that defines a `__call__` signature.

Comment: I'd like to enforce that the `__init__` method of `obj` have the necessary arguments that allow it to work with the rest of the library code, but give the freedom to users of this library to also add their own additional constructor arguments

Comment: but you never call the `__init__` method on an `obj` that's already been constructed...

Comment: sure, that was not the right example, in the actual function, `obj` is constructed inside of it — but I think the argument would still hold for any other method that is not `__init__` anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: I believe you have an actual use case here, but I don't think either of your examples represent it in a way where answering them is going to be useful to you.  :)  Like I said, what you probably want to do is define a protocol for the function that constructs `obj`, which is not the same thing as the class of `obj`.

Comment: I agree indeed, I should reformulate the question